# My 96 honda civic will not start please help!

Tags: ignition, power-windows, fuse

Ok I will try to make this quick and short as much as I can. so a couple weeks ago I put the drivers side power door on my 96 Honda civic hatch. everything went well until a couple of days ago I tried putting the passenger power door on. once I made all my connections and thought it was good (I connected the wires that gave power to the doors to the fuse box) I tried the switch on the passenger door window and it worked. so then I tried it through the drivers side and it rolled down. here's where it all messed up. I switched the window locked switch from on to off and my doors stopped working, and now my car will not start.

These are all the things I thought could be wrong. I checked the clutch safety switch I checked the fuses I looked at the starter and tested the wires but everything seemed to have current I then took out the fuse box to see if anything had burned out but I find nothing everything tested good. I have no clue what it can be.

I hope I gave enough info and if you have questions please ask I really don't want to take this to a shop and spend an arm and both legs. thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing that changed between the time it worked and the time it didn't work was the passenger door, I'd be willing to bet that's your problem.  Since there is no way to diagnose the specific electrical malfunction with this site, I suggest removing all the connections from the passenger door, and verifying that everything works as it should (car starts, driver side door controls work, all other electrical components work, etc.)  Then, do the passenger door, adding one control at a time.  If there is a wire that is grounding out, you will have a better idea which wire it is by limiting the possibilities.

Comment: I disconnected both doors but I still get nothing... Still no clue thanks though